# Django: "Invalid default value" during "migrate" command

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is a simple model

```
class Baz(models.Model):
  FOO = ('foo', 'Foo')
  BAR = ('bar', 'Bar')
  FOO_BAR = (FOO, BAR)

  foo_bar = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=FOO, choices=FOO_BAR)
```

After making migrations via `python manage.py makemigrations`, when trying to migrate, getting error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'foo_bar'")
```

Tried to put `('foo', 'Foo')` explicitly with no result. Tried to use `FOO_BAR[0]` - same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: foo_bar field is a CharField, default expect a string not a tuple, so  `foo_bar = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=FOO[0], choices=FOO_BAR)` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't point to thee variable as default value, you should provide the real value that will be saved:

```
foo_bar = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='foo', choices=FOO_BAR)
```